# Creating a Plugin for Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: tor

I am writing a plugin for Firefox to evaluate the security of a web page. If I write this for Firefox, will it be able to be ported into the Tor browser?

Is it advisable to run plugins in the Tor browser?

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you run the Tor browser with the default settings to prevent browser fingerprinting. Tor even [warns you](https://m.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/34u6m9/why_does_tor_warns_me_about_using_monitor_size/) when you change the browser's window size. Installing browser extensions is certainly inadvisable.